# How to limit user to use limite duration of service of my flutter android application? Lo

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-play

I am building an app for video editing...
I want to give some free minutes for 1st time using of  app . User can edit the videos until the completion free minutes .
These minutes count based on duration of video which is editing..

After that they have to purchase for further any duration of videos..?

**How can I limit user to use some until free minutes?**

Till now I didn't used any online service in my app. Everything worked on device.
Any way to implement it on offline.?
If not possible..
What can I do to tackle it..?

I not a native English speaker..
Try to understand...  :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a timer that will trigger when no time is left.
It works **completely offline** .
This goes in the Class outside any other method where you usually declare your variables: (Note that you can set the time you want in millis. I chose 10000ms so 10 seconds as an example)

```
private CountDownTimer timer;
private long secondsLeft = 10000; // how much milliseconds of 
// free time you want to have
```

//
And this goes where you want to start the time.

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(secondsLeft, 1000) {  
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        secondsLeft = millisUntilFinished/1000;
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // The time is up! User has spent the time
    }  
}.start();
```

Then add these (or if you already have these methods then add the code in them to your ones.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    timer.cancel();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    timer = new CountDownTimer(secondsLeft, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            secondsLeft = millisUntilFinished/1000;
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            // The time is up! The user has used the app for your amount of time
        }
    }.start();

}
```

Note: To make it survive an app restart or a phone restart you have to save "secondsLeft" to your device and load it when the app starts.

Comment: Does this help you?